# React DOM element mounts and unmounts on every render when it should instead be updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, callback, ref

According to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), callback refs are called when a component mounts (with the value of the DOM element) and unmounts (with null):

> React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the
> component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.

According to the docs on [React reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#dom-elements-of-the-same-type), DOM elements of the same type will be updated instead of replaced when encountered:

> When comparing two React DOM elements of the same type, React looks at
> the attributes of both, keeps the same underlying DOM node, and only
> updates the changed attributes.

In the following simple snippet, we log every time the callback ref is called:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
    
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
    
  return (
    <div>
      <table ref={(ref) => console.log(ref)}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{num}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={() => setNum((prev) => prev + 1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

... and surprisingly, it is called every time the component renders, indicating that the connected DOM node is also unmounted and mounted every time the component rerenders.

**Why is this? Seems I don't understand the docs or there is some other mechanism at play here which I would like to understand.**

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-mount-unmount-lr10wv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called because you passed callback as anonymous function, which will be recreated each time you update the state(thus forcing rerender), and when `ref` gets the new value(recomputed function with new reference) it will trigger callback execution. You can avoid this by stabilizing ref callback reference, like this:

```
  import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const refCallback = useCallback((ref) => console.log(ref), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table ref={refCallback}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{num}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={() => setNum((prev) => prev + 1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So the consensus is that whenever a component is given a new ref it unmounts? Then this is a special case because when other props change, the component does not unmount, but is simply rerendered and updated, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I understood it. And that is why we use `useRef`, because it exposes stable reference that we can use to pass it to the `ref` prop to any element, and like that avoiding unnecessary mounts/unmounts of the elements.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is the same if we use `const aRef = useRef()` along with anonymous function `ref => aRef.current = ref`. We still have the anonymous function which results in the same mount/unmount pattern as above. We would HAVE to create a stable function reference to avoid this. Seems these usecases are so common it should be documented how it impacts things... I mean my intuitive understanding was that callback refs fired on every render and this is the reason why they actually do :) https://codesandbox.io/s/table-mount-unmount-2-dkhl4h

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying, you should instead do `const aRef = useRef()` and then `ref={aRef}`, then we avoid this... But still, the usecase with a callback ref is quite common so (not memoizing it), and not evident to me that the component actively unmounts and remounts when a new ref / callback ref is given. Would be nice to see it documented since it is a special case compared to other props (ofc `ref` is generally special so maybe not so unexpected).

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking with `useRef`. Although this is different usecase than one you described in OP, with callbacks. But anyway they both have in common that stable reference is a must, in order to avoid unnecessary unmonuts.

Comment: Yeah, noticed it works the same when you use `forwardRef` with a custom component; any other prop may change without mounting / unmounting but as soon as the `ref` changes, the component is unmounted and remounted. Great, thanks!

Comment: Or actually, that was wrong, the custom component itself does NOT unmount, but the ref is still called with `null` in between renders, so I guess the bottom line is that callback refs are called with `null` BOTH when the component unmounts but ALSO when the ref is simply changed (without unmounting the component): https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs

Comment: Well it looks like it is, I didn't manage to find that link while reading about. I just inspected this behaviour by simply logging into ref-referenced component, inside CDM, CDU and CWU, and indeed it is not unmounting, but rather performing double execution of ref callback as link you provided claims.  Now thank you! :)